Windows 10 not found after installing Bliss OS
I have a problem similar to this one: Windows 10 disk not found when trying to boot from Grub
I installed BlissOS next to Windows 10. Booting BlissOS works but booting Windows results in error: Error: disk 'hdWindows' not found.
I tried changing boot type in BIOS (Dual Boot, Legacy Boot, UEFI Boot). Legacy boot doesn't even load grub. Two others load grub but don't boot Windows.
My hardware: DFI EC200-BT.
Here is Boot-Info: https://sprunge.us/PNgMsx
Is it safe to try autofix of the Boot-Repair tool? If not, how else can I fix the issue to be able to boot both Windows and BlissOS?

You're asking a question about fixing Windows to a site intended for Unix/Linux. Even if that's because you installed Linux you got this problem, that's still not the best site to ask it. Try superuser instead.

I believe grub is related more to Linux than Windows plus the referenced question was already on this platform that's why it seemed natural to post here. Thanks for the information anyway!

You have old BIOS installs with very old MBR(msdos) partitioning. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives since 2012 and release of Windows 8. Boot-Repair primarily is to fix grub issues. It will not fix Windows issues. For Windows you need Windows repair tools. Grub also only boots working Windows or no chkdsk nor fast startup/hibernation in Windows. With UEFI you can always boot Windows from UEFI boot menu, but with BIOS you have to temporarily install Windows boot loader, fix Windows & then restore grub with Boot-Repair or manually.
